# Is it possible to have a 5-feedback score in oDesk?

Tags: odesk

For example I see this [Freelancer public profile](https://www.odesk.com/o/profiles/users/_~01497b2b5704a183d7/) has 10 5-star reviews, yet 4.99 of  feedback score. Why not 5?

Answer (score 1):

Although often slightly under 5, it seems 5 is possible (if I am interpreting the significance correctly) [eg](https://www.odesk.com/o/profiles/users/_~0165a1d97ac78fbd9e/):

[image: WA62692 example]

Comment: Thanks, I wonder how oDesk computes this average feedback score. Any idea how 10 5-star reviews can be averaged to 4.99? Since every feedback is a combinations of a couple of different subfeedbacks does that mean he got a 4-star somewhere?